# Finding the Third Side of a Triangle Composed of Vectors

Tags: trigonometry

Imagine a beam of light emanating from a point in space and striking a surface. Then, for any other point on that surface, I want to know the distance from that point to the light vector.

[image]

What I have so far is this:

```
g X (f - l) = len(g) * len(f - l) * sin(theta)
 sin(theta) = g X (f - l) / len(g) * len(f - l)
```

Because it's a right triangle:

```
d = sin(theta) * (f - l)
```

I've already found that

```
sin(theta) = g X (f - l) / len(g) * len(f - l)
```

Therefore:

```
d = (g X (f - l)) * (f - l) / len(g) * len(f - l)
```

But I feel like I've done something wrong. Is my method for finding d correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're mixing up which quantities are vectors and which are scalars. Remember that
a cross product of two vectors is a vector, so your first equation in vector form should be
  \begin{align*}
    \vec{g} \times \vec{(f-l)} = ||\vec{g}||\cdot||\vec{f-l}||\cdot\sin(\theta)\vec{n}
  \end{align*}
where $\vec{n}$ is a unit vector pointing into the page. Probably more useful to you is that same formula after taking magnitudes on both sides:
  \begin{align*}
    ||\vec{g} \times \vec{(f-l)}|| = ||\vec{g}||\cdot||\vec{f-l}||\cdot\sin(\theta).
  \end{align*}
In your second equation, recall that the sine function measures the ratios of lengths of sides, so we have to use $||\vec{f-l}||$ rather than just $\vec{f-l}$:
  \begin{align*}
    d = \sin(\theta) \cdot ||\vec{f-l}||.
  \end{align*}
Putting these last two equations together, we get
  \begin{align*}
    d = \frac{||\vec{g}\times \vec{(f-l)}||\cdot ||\vec{(f-l)}||}
      {||\vec{g}||\cdot||\vec{(f-l)}||}
      = \frac{||\vec{g}\times \vec{(f-l)}||}{||\vec{g}||}.
  \end{align*}